# Why does this Bash code not run until I exit screen?

Tags: linux, bash

I have written some Bash code, which should run a script that goes in as root and runs some commands, then screen a screen session, then run another script in that screen session. The script is here:

```
#!/bin/bash
su root -c ./screenRoot.sh
cd /media/kiancross/Minecraft_Server/MinecraftServer/1.6.4_Server
screen -d -m -S MinecraftServer
screen -r MinecraftServer
./start.sh
```

screenRoot.sh contains the following code that is run:

```
#!/bin/bash
chmod u+s $(which screen)
chmod 755 /var/run/screen
rm -fr /var/run/screen/*
exit
```

For some reason, when I run the first code, it waits for mew to exit from the screen I have created before it will run the ./start.sh script.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `./start.sh` as the command argument to `screen`:

```
#!/bin/bash
su root -c ./screenRoot.sh
cd /media/kiancross/Minecraft_Server/MinecraftServer/1.6.4_Server
screen -d -m -S MinecraftServer ./start.sh
screen -r MinecraftServer
```